# What is this AttributeError in django mongodb, and how do I prevent this?

Tags: django, mongodb

I keep running into this error for both .raw_query and .filter,

it happens when I do a simple query like this :

Tried `google` but did not have much luck except [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-non-relational/9buyMWEHLkc%29) .

Is that the same issue? And how do I update the schema to prevent this from happening?

```
from app.models import Poll
import Datetime

polls = Poll.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.datetime(2013,5,1))
for p  in polls: 
    print p
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actual piece of code that's returning the error?

Comment: And traceback ... But I think that `polls` is a string. Probably a mistake in the variable name.